# Full screen flexislider with responsive images

Tags: jquery, html, css

### The Problem

I'm trying to use the FlexSlider plugin to create a full page slider. Almost identical to the Suzy Hoodless [website](http://suzyhoodless.com/project/). I'm having problems getting the images in my slides to stretch them to fit 100% of the height.

### Update

So I've managed to work around the problem using this code

I'm now trying to make sure that the images are centred and cropped on **BOTH** sides rather than just the right side when the browser is resized. Any thoughts?

```
<div class="flexslider-container">
<div class="flexslider">
      <ul class="slides">
            <li><img src="images/kitchen_adventurer_donut.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/kitchen_adventurer_caramel.jpg" /></li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

```
.flexslider-container, .flexslider .slides, .flex-viewport {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}

.flexslider {
position: absolute; 
margin: 0; 
padding: 0; 
width: 100%; 
height: 100%; 
overflow: hidden;
}

.flexslider .slides > li {
width: 100%; 
height: 100%; 
display: none; 
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; /* Hide the slides before the JS is loaded. Avoids image jumping */
}

.flexslider .slides img { 
min-width: 100%; 
min-height: 100%; 
display: block;
}
```

Comment: Post the code you've tried.

Comment: Code attached above!

Answer (score 0):

You could try using background-images instead of images, then use background-size: cover. See the example in the fiddle below.

http://jsfiddle.net/67z3q6gL/3/

```
.flexslider .slides > li {
    background-size: cover; 
    background-position: center;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: none; 
    -webkit-backface-visibility:   hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this Jon :) Oddly I didn't even have another container around my .flexslider class. That's made a big difference. Managed a work around without using background images too.